# Unidentified Plant that started blooming

Tags: identification, flowers

This plant was originally growing in the soil. I thought it was a weed then it started blooming, and now I am curious what plant this is. The flowers are highly fragrant. Thank you in advance :) [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This a petunia!  Lucky lucky you!  This just might be a trailing petunia that stays low and works great in hanging baskets.  My advice?  Snip those flowers off as soon as you are able.  With each flower just know there will be 10 or 20 behind it because you cut that flower off.  These are annuals.

Annuals have but ONE job in this life and that is to produce seed.  They are serious about this job.  If you keep cutting of the seed babies the flowers then the plant gets even more vigorous, larger produces massive amounts of flowers to offset what ever troll is killing its babies.

The more flowers you cut off the more that plant will get energized and grow bigger, stronger and produce many more flowers than had you...made the mistake most do and let the flower stay, and go to seed.

Once that flower is allowed to make seed that plant is done.  Well, the seed is signals to the seed counters (humanized) and as long as that plant knows it has produced some seed it will just start dying slowly and surely.  It has done its job in life.

A little balanced fertilizer would do wonders.  Have you added any fertilizer?  Too much nitrogen and you'll get lots of leaves few flowers.

Comment: Oh Jurp beat me...grins!  See that weed in the upper part of the picture?  Pull it.  Before it flowers.  Grins...chickweed?

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice :) I would love there for plentiful blooms for the limited amount of time it will stay alive and I will start cutting those flowers. The blooms are beautiful and the reminds me of the night sky. I haven't put any fertilizer, but will, thanks to your help

Answer (score 6):

It's a petunia (cultivar Blue Morn? Starry Night?) - an annual - and will continue blooming throughout the growing season if you remove the spent blooms ("deadheading"). To have more of this plant for next year, you may want to stop deadheading the plant in late August and then let the seeds fall on the ground beneath it.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I will definitely do that, it's has such beautiful and unique flowers.

Comment: Jurp you must be imagining OLD SPECIES of petunias.  The petunias of today are all sterilized or similar.  No seeds will be happening, trust me.  Forget about trying to promote seed from a petunia...anymore!

Comment: To propagate vegetatively means some sort of a Federal Crime against patent laws...I am serious here.

Comment: Looks like Starry Night to me; I've got some of those in my garden, and they started flowering this week.

Comment: Stormy - Because the poster mentioned that it came up by itself, that indicated to me that it was not a sterile cultivar.

Comment: In my experience, old varieties of Petunia are highly fragrant, while the new ones have little or no fragrance at all. I don't know the name of the cultivar, but if it's higly fragrant, there's a better chance of it being an old one, also that reseeds itself.